# Replacing for loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program in c sharp, without any loop of decisional statements, but I don't know how to get rid of for loop statement.

```
public int score()
{
    int scor = 0;
    int i=0;
    int type;
    for(int frameIndex=0; frameIndex < 10; frameIndex++)
    {
        type=Convert.ToInt32(isStrike(i));
        scor+=getStrikeCalculation(i)*type;
        i+=1*type;
        type=Convert.ToInt32(isSpare(i));
        scor+=getSpareCalculation(i)*type;
        i+=2*type;
        type=Convert.ToInt32(isNormal(i));
        scor += getNormalCalculation(i)*type;
        i+=2*type;
    }
    return scor;
}
private bool isNormal(int i)
{
    return rolls[i]+rolls[i+1]!=10 && rolls[i]!=10;
}
private bool isSpare(int i){
    return rolls[i] + rolls[i+1] == 10;
}
private bool isStrike(int i){
    return rolls[i] == 10;
}
private int getStrikeCalculation(int i){
    return rolls[i]+ rolls[i+1] + rolls[i+2];
}
private int getNormalCalculation(int i){
    return rolls[i]+rolls[i+1];
}
private int getSpareCalculation(int i){
    return rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1] + rolls[i + 2];
}
```

I tried to make score recursive but it didn't work, with recursion I don't know how to stop the function, since I can't use if statements.

Comment: You could use LINQ, but where are these crazy requirements coming from? Why can't you use a loop?

Comment: Why can’t you use an if statement?

Comment: The adjective you're looking for is "conditional" not "decisional".

Comment: You can use `foreach` loop within a range of an interval you want. someting like `foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0,9)) {...}` or use Joels solutions.

Comment: Is `select/case` allowed?

Comment: I want to build a shack, but I can’t use a hammer or screw driver.

Comment: If this is some homework question that requires you to use different constructs then just say so. Otherwise these requirements are senseless.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, is allowed

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek not really, just a debate with a friend and he said he can do this, but not telling me how

Comment: The `isStrike()` logic is wrong. You can roll a gutterball on the first half of a frame and still pick up the spare in the second half.

Answer (score 5):

Your loop simply does something ten times. If you want no loops, just do the thing ten times:

```
int scor = 0;
int i=0;
int type;
int frameIndex=0;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isStrike(i));
scor+=getStrikeCalculation(i)*type;
i+=1*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isSpare(i));
scor+=getSpareCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isNormal(i));
scor += getNormalCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
frameIndex += 1;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isStrike(i));
scor+=getStrikeCalculation(i)*type;
i+=1*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isSpare(i));
scor+=getSpareCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isNormal(i));
scor += getNormalCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
frameIndex += 1;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isStrike(i));
scor+=getStrikeCalculation(i)*type;
i+=1*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isSpare(i));
scor+=getSpareCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
type=Convert.ToInt32(isNormal(i));
scor += getNormalCalculation(i)*type;
i+=2*type;
frameIndex += 1;
... and so on, seven more times.
```

Why on earth you would want to do so is beyond me; the point of a loop is to *avoid* writing the code out ten times. Why do you want to do this strange thing? Just write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Range()`

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(frameIndex => {
    type=Convert.ToInt32(isStrike(i));
    scor+=getStrikeCalculation(i)*type;
    i+=1*type;
    type=Convert.ToInt32(isSpare(i));
    scor+=getSpareCalculation(i)*type;
    i+=2*type;
    type=Convert.ToInt32(isNormal(i));
    scor += getNormalCalculation(i)*type;
    i+=2*type;
});
```

Of course, there's still a loop here. It's just hidden away behind a method someone else wrote so you don't have to see it in your own code. But then, silly requirements make for silly solutions.